# How to use circular progress button library on android 4.0 lower?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-drawable, nineoldandroids

I want to use [circular-progress-button](https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/circular-progress-button) on android 2.2 or above. But there is a error on Property class that say minimum sdk must be 14.

I don't want to check sdk version and then use or not.

Or even is there any alternative library like this?

Comment: You may be able to port using the [nineoldandroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) library (as in changing imports, and calls to the `Animators`, etc) but proper animations APIs were introduced after Android 2.3 and devs rarely want to spend time backporting

Comment: @A--C 2.3?! But error say minimum sdk is 14!

Comment: Yeah, `14` pertains to ICS. By backporting using the library I mentioned, you would be able to (hopefully) use the progress button on 2.2 (sdk `8`) and above. Of course, once you backport, you will change `minimumSdk` to `8` rather than `14`. I'm not suggesting a magic solution. All I'm saying is if you can't find anything that supports API 8 and above, you can try doing it *yourself* using the library I linked you to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove that error maybe you need to increase `android:minSdkVersion` to 14, which means you cant support bellow Android 4.0.

But there is another library with  `android:minSdkVersion=11`. You can use that library too. Here is the link:
[FABProgressCircle](https://github.com/JorgeCastilloPrz/FABProgressCircle)

Comment: I knew how to resolve that error, but just looking for a alternative library that support below Android 4.x, preferred above 2.2; But  introduced link was good enough,Thanks.